# How do I use a script that contains paths to other files regardless of its location?

Tags: bash, symlink

I have a script stored in a particular directory nested deep within other directories.

`a/long/path/to/the/script.sh`

I created a hard link to the script from my desktop, so it might be easier to access.

However, the paths to other files programmed in the script refuses to work while executing the desktop hard link.

I now receive 'No such file or directory.' error.

I don't want to create additional sym links to these files, as it seems messy.

I'm not sure what to do, please help.

Comment: Did you write the script? You could make the first command in the script `cd a/long/path/to/the` to change the current working directory of the script when you run it.  The path that you `cd` to should be absolute though. Or, you could make sure that all the paths in the script are absolute.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's a brilliant idea. Thank you! 

P.S. Just learnt I could change the paths to the files in the script to absolute paths. I think either of these solutions could work.

Comment: Also, read [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 1):

If the script uses relative path to locate files and/or directories, then its current working directory has to be correct for it to find these.

You change the current working directory with the `cd` command.  If the first command in the file is a `cd` command that changes directory to an absolute path where the script expects to be executing from, then the paths later in the script would be correct.

For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /some/path/where/we/expect/to/be || exit 1

# (rest of script here)
```

This would change directory (or exit the script prematurely if that was not possible) before the rest of the script runs.

This would have the added benefit that you may place the script anywhere where you think it's convenient to keep it.

The other way to solve this would be to change all the paths in the script to be absolute paths.

Comment: This works! Thank you!